# indentation error while rendering template with django jinja

Tags: django, django-templates, django-views

I have this template in django 1.8 which gives me an indentation error :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head lang="en">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title></title>
    <a href={% url 'do-math' %}> df loaded</a>
</head>
<body>

</body>
</html>
```

The error is :
Error during template rendering
In template /file_loaded.html, error at line 6

```
" <a href=
      {% url 'do-math' %}
      > df loaded</a>"
```

Any idea ?
Here is my url file :

```
 urlpatterns = [     url(r'^admin/'                  , include(admin.site.urls)                      ),
                        url(r'upload'                   , 'upload_csv.views.upload_csv'                 ),
                        url('program_set_up2'           , 'upload_csv.views.program_set_up'             ),
                        url(r'^medias/(?P<path>.*)$'    , serve, {'document_root': settings.MEDIA_ROOT} ),
                        url(r'^do_math/'                  , 'do_math.views.init'                      , name='do-math' )]
```

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I got it.
The error was not in the template itself, but in the pointed view. 
I guess when the 'url' function is called, it does check the integrity of the corresponding function. Then if it find an indentation error on this function, an error is raised. The problem is that the error is raise as if coming from the template itself, and not clearly pointing out to the actual faulty code (the pointed view).
So, if you find this error, have a look to the pointed view !

Comment: You may want to include the error in views and how you fixed it to help other people who have this problem in the future.

Answer (score 0):

While not the cause of the error, unless the quotation marks are included in the 'do-math' variable of the context, you will also want to change this:

```
<a href={% url 'do-math' %}> df loaded</a>
```

to this:

```
<a href="{% url 'do-math' %}"> df loaded</a>
```

Most browsers will render either fine, but URLs should be quoted. Good luck.